# What is the root of angular2 application?

Tags: angular

As [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) as the root of all the application scopes in angularjs, what we have as a root level component in angular2?

> Is it the application component which bootstraps the app?

Answer (score 1):

You have to bootstrap the root component

```
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

This component contains all components and directives of a single Angular application. More than one Application can be bootstrapped on one page.

This is not the root scope though because there is no scope in Angular2.

You can create shared services that are global to your application use it **like** a root scope.

If a service (plain class with an `@Injectable()` decorator) is provided in `bootstrap()` or the `providers` of the root application **and nowhere else** then there will only this single instance in this specific Angular application

```
@Injectable() 
class RootScopeService { 
  // not a common name in Angular2 applications
  // I just used it for demo purposes
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [RootScopeService]);
```

Everywhere where it is injected, the same instance will be injected.

```
class SomeComponentOrDirective {
  constructor(private rootScope:RootScopeService) {}
}
```

If you want the global service (`RootScopeService`) to do anything you need to add methods, properties, observables yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Any class can be a "rootScope", you just have to add it in the bootstrap method

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [MyRoot]);
```

Also you don't need to put @Injectable, it's not mandatory

```
export class MyRoot{ 
 this.user = "AngJobs";
 this.usersOnline = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple term

> Angular 1.x (`ng-app`) = Angular 2.x (`bootstrap(component, [...])`)

in angular 1.x we Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page.

same case in angular2 we have to use `bootstrap` keyword with the component name that specify which the root level of our app, whihc is the entry point for our app, there are lot of functionality's  that we can provide/specify at the time of booting our app that includes :-

- Inject Shared/Global services or variables
- Inject shared Directives
- Bound multiple components/directives with PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES (by doing so these are available throughout the whole app than no need to provide in the list of directives and providers every time.)

basic syntax for the same is as :-

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [shared_serivces_directives]);
```

First attribute of bootstrap is component's class name which we have to load first time when load our project.

than as second parameter which is optional, here we can provide Common directives, services and much more.

also there is no `$rootscope`  in angular2 like in angular1.x

I hope this clears everything related to Rootlevel of angular2 app.